# Save a tiff as single strip using SixLabors ImageSharp

Tags: tiff, imagesharp, sixlabors.imagesharp

Is there a way to save a tiff (that isn't already single strip) as a single strip tiff, i.e. one where ImageLength == RowsPerStrip.

I was hoping there was a `TiffEncoder` parameter or some other way of controlling this.

When I call SaveAsTiff the RowsPerStrip is preserved, which is what I would expect, but not what I desire.